# iOS ,NSDocumentDirectory get the nsurl or path file

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsurl

i have this code for saving the mp3 files

```
NSArray *documentPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docDirectory = [documentPath objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *fileName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@.mp3", dateString ,timeString ];


    NSURL* fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:myString];
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL options:0 error:&error];

     NSString *savePath = [docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    [data writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];
```

now i want read this file by **MPMoviePlayerController**

how can get the path or nsurl file

--- somthing code same this

```
 NSURL * urlv = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:myString];
     avPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:urlv];
    [avPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [avPlayer play];
```

please help for searching the mystrig  or nsurl source

Comment: do you want `savePath`'s value in `myString`?

Comment: i want read the path file to my string

Comment: Instead of local variable of `savePath` create a `@property` then you can access it thoughout the class.

Comment: how to access in the class please help me for geting the path file 
because i can read the file in itunes but i want read the local file in app

Comment: for example i want to read the file name 20130410094215.mp3 is saved in NSDocumentDirectory how to call this mp3 for playing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
NSString *filename = @"whatever you've saved your filename as";
NSArray *pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [pathArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *yourSoundPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:soundPath])
{
    NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath isDirectory:NO];
}

//Then just init your player with the contents of that URL
```